# how to let href or url open a \\ address

Tags: hyperref

I have a address, like `\\server\folder\`, how to let `\href` or `\url` open it? I try both:

```
\url{run:\\\\server\\folder\\}
\url{\\\\server\\folder\\}
```

it does't work, but I can directly copy `\\server\folder\` to my file browser and open it. When I put mouse on it in pdf, it show this:
[image]

Comment: url never use `\\ ` separator even on windows, perhaps you want `file:///server/folder/` but I'm not sure what you want that to do from a pdf reader?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle under windows, I can copy `\\server\folder\` to my file manager and open this folder on server in file manager, I would like my pdf can direct this link to my file manager as well

Comment: i change my code to `\url{file:\\\\server\\folder\\}`, it can open directly the folder in pdf

Comment: yes but the windows file path `\\server\folder` shoudl relate to the URL `file:///server/folder/` but not all systems get this right. Anyway if you have something working feel free to post an answer!